# How to iterate select items in an array

Tags: jquery

I have an array of 5 items.

I know if I want to step through all 5 items I can use:

```
$.each(response.data.items, function(i,data)
{
// code 
}
```

However, how can I chose to step through just items `2` and `4` in the array, still applying the same `// code` above?

I.e. in pseudocode this would be `for items 2 and 4 do: this`.

Comment: Use `for` instead. `for (i = 2, len = response.data.items.length; i <= 4 && i < length; ++i)`

Comment: @zerkms thanks, doesn't your code also include item 3 though? I just want 2 and 4

Comment: What's wrong with `response.data.items[2]` & `response.data.items[4]`? Did i misunderstood the question?

Comment: @A.Wolff that would be inefficient; I'd have to repeat the code I was applying to the items each time

Comment: @alias51 Replace `++i` with `i += 2`. Sometimes please try bring some effort in your problems.

Comment: @zerkms because I might have 100 items and want 3, 24, 54, 57, 66... etc

Comment: If you really want to use `jquery.each` against the `response.data.items` array: api documentation states _We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false._ **Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration.**...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through an array of the indexes that you want:

```
$.each([2, 4], function(i)
{
  var data = response.data.items[i];
  // code 
}
```

Comment: how would this work if i wanted to repeat the code for every 3 items? e.g. 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, etc

Comment: @alias51: If you want to loop all items and do something special for every third item, you can use `if (i % 3 == 0)` to check for the first of the three, or `if (i % 3 == 2)` for the last of the three.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=2; i < response.data.items.length; i+=2){ // code }
```

if you want to access items at specific indexes why don't you just use `array[i]` ?

Comment: how would this work if i wanted to repeat the code for every 3 items? e.g. 1-3, 4-6, 7-9, etc

Comment: You could use two variable and increment them by three. Like for(i=1, j=3; j < response.data.items.length; i+=3, j+=3){ // code }